# Event Tracking not working - Possibly an issue with tracking code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

We've setup event tracking to track when a user clicks a button, but it is not tracking. I've made sure our IP is not filtered out, and RealTime data in Google Analytics shows my activity throughout the site, so I know we're good there. The code I'm using is the same I use on every other site, so this seems correct. Here's an example:

```
<a href="/buy-local.html" target="_blank" class="red_box_white_type" style="float: left; margin-right: 3em;" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Local', 'Buy', 'Indoor');">Buy Local</a>
```

Everything here looks fine, so I wonder if the reason it's not tracking has something to do with the way the GA code is setup. Here's that code:

```
<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-42644009-29', 'auto');
        ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

        ga('create', 'UA-20741841-1', 'auto', 'hpcFire');
        ga('hpcFire.require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('hpcFire.send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

This is a Joomla site. Could that have something to do with why Event Tracking isn't working? All other tracking appears to be working.

Comment: Are you checking the correct property? I noticed you have multiple trackers, so your event is tracking into the nameless one (ie. UA-42644009-29).

Comment: That's the issue. Thank you! The UA-42644009-29 is a newer account that the client setup, but doesn't really need. UA-20741841-1 is the main account. Would you suggest that we just remove the 3 lines of code with the UA-42644009-29 number to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track into the `UA-20741841-1` property without using named trackers, then I would suggest the following changes:

1. Replace `UA-42644009-29` with `UA-20741841-1` in this block

   ```
   ga('create', 'UA-42644009-29', 'auto');
   ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
   ```
2. Remove the following code:

   ```
   ga('create', 'UA-20741841-1', 'auto', 'hpcFire');
   ga('hpcFire.require', 'displayfeatures');
   ga('hpcFire.send', 'pageview');
   ```

In this way, your unnamed tracker will be tracking in the desired property, and you won't have to change any of the onlick code because those are already not using any tracker names.